# Why constructor is being called twice

Tags: c++

I do not understand how `constructors work`?

Here I have declared an object `obj2`. It calls constructor `abc()`, which is perfectly fine.

But when I am assigning

```
obj2 =  100
```

Why does compiler allow initializing an integer to a class object? If at all it is allowing then how it is destroying the object and then how it is calling another parameterized constructor.

Now I have another question why `destructor` is called only once as there are `two` objects?

One more doubt I have is, compiler is `not doing anything` with `default constructor` then why default constructor is `required`?

```
class abc{
public:
    int a, b;

    abc()
    {a = 0; b = 0;}

    abc(int x)
    {a = x;}

    ~abc()
    {std::cout << "Destructor Called\n";}
};
int main()
{
    abc obj1;
    cout << "OBJ1 " << obj1.a << "..." << obj1.b << "\n";
    abc obj2;
    cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "..." << obj2.b << "\n";
    obj2 = 100;
    cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

`output:`

```
OBJ1 0...0
OBJ2 0...0
Destructor Called
OBJ2 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us play show and tell, so let us instrument *all* special members:

```
#include <iostream>

class abc{
public:
    int a, b;

    abc()
    { std::cout << "Default constructor\n"; a = 0; b = 0;}

    abc(int x)
    { std::cout << "Int constructor\n"; a = x;}

    abc(abc const& other): a(other.a), b(other.b)
    { std::cout << "Copy constructor (" << a << ", " << b << ")\n"; }

    abc& operator=(abc const& other) {
      std::cout << "Assignment operator (" << a << ", " << b << ") = (" << other.a << ", " << other.b << ")\n";
      a = other.a;
      b = other.b;
      return *this;
    }

    ~abc()
    {std::cout << "Destructor Called\n";}
};

int main()
{
    abc obj1;
    std::cout << "OBJ1 " << obj1.a << "..." << obj1.b << "\n";
    abc obj2;
    std::cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "..." << obj2.b << "\n";
    obj2 = 100;
    std::cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And we obtain [this output](http://ideone.com/h3If6L):

```
Default constructor
OBJ1 0...0
Default constructor
OBJ2 0...0
Int constructor
Assignment operator (0, 0) = (100, 0)
Destructor Called
OBJ2 100
Destructor Called
Destructor Called
```

So, let's reconcile them with line sources:

```
int main()
{
    abc obj1;
    // Default constructor

    std::cout << "OBJ1 " << obj1.a << "..." << obj1.b << "\n";
    // OBJ1 0...0

    abc obj2;
    // Default constructor

    std::cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "..." << obj2.b << "\n";
    // OBJ2 0...0

    obj2 = 100;
    // Int constructor
    // Assignment operator (0, 0) = (100, 0)
    // Destructor Called

    std::cout << "OBJ2 " << obj2.a << "\n";
    // OBJ2 100

    return 0;
    // Destructor Called
    // Destructor Called
}
```

You mostly had it all, let us examine the surprises.

First surprise: even though `obj2` changes value later `abc obj2;` will still call the default constructor at the point of declaration.

Second surprise: `obj2 = 100` actually means `obj2.operator=(abc(100));`, that is:

- Build a temporary (unnamed) `abc` from `abc(100)`
- Assign it to `obj2`
- Destroy the temporary before moving on to the next statement

Third surprise: destructors are called at the end of the scope, right before the closing bracket `}` (and yes, *after* the `return`). Since you are using `system("pause")` I assume you are on Windows => though luck they are called after you end the pause and thus your console Windows disappears in the blink of an eye at the moment they would have appeared. You can either launch the program from a more permanent console, or use an extra scope:

```
int main () {
  {
    // your code here
  }
  system("pause"); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> > 

But when I am assigning obj2 = 100, how the compiler is allowing initializing an integer to a class object?

This is because when you do the following:

```
obj2 = 100;
```

this one will first call `abc(int x)` to generate an object of the class, then call the default copy assignment operator (since no user-defined is provided) to assign the value 100 to existing `obj2`. After the assignment, the temporary object is destructed.

If you do not desire this effect, mark the constructor as `explict` to avoid implicit calls.

```
explicit abc(int x) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 obj2 = 100;
```

You defined a constructor which takes an `int`.  This allows for an implicit conversion from int to `abc`.  This requires the creation of a new object.  It doesn't just magically set a field in the existing object by calling a constructor; constructors *construct* new objects.

EDIT: Correct sequence of events from @Steve Jessop

> A new instance is created, then copy-assigned to the original, then the temporary (not the original) is destroyed. The copy assignment does indeed magically set both fields in the existing object.

Comment: "the first instance is destroyed and a new instance is created which takes the place of the original" -- that's not right. A new instance is created, then copy-assigned to the original, then the temporary (not the original) is destroyed. The copy assignment does indeed magically set both fields in the existing object.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Good call

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is constructor which can take an argument of `int` type. That temporary created object is copied to `obj2` by invoking default copy-assignment.

To avoid such conversions, mark constructor as explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You're destructor is called 3 times, you can't see it because of the pause.

Comment: In place of `pause` i have used "getchar()" but still i could able to see only once destructor call

Comment: You'll see them *after* you press a key.

Comment: But he's not seeing them because his output window goes away when he presses a key :-)

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak the destructors are not called until after main is out of scope (or going out of scope). If your IDE won't let you see the output before the window goes away then; 1) run from shell or 2) log output to a file.

Comment: Why do people build the project this way in the first place? If you Debug > Start Without Debugging or press Ctrl-F5, it automatically pauses AFTER the app has wholly terminated but before the window closes.

Comment: @kfsone: because (a) historical reasons, and (b) educators apparently find it easier to teach this stupid thing than to remind newbies a hundred times that they should start the program a particular way.